# Is there a Regular Expression for blank input?

Tags: regex

This might be a silly question but is there a Regular Expression to validate for `blanks` or no user input at all?

Comment: What language/tool are you working with?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start of line immediately followed by end of line:

```
^$
```

Any amount of whitespace, including none:

```
^\s*$
```

Answer (score 4):

`^$` should do the trick. `^` matches the beginning and `$` the end of the string.